# Chart "Plan" Versus "Actual" for a time series?

Tags: charts

What kind of charts show **Plan** (forecast) versus **Actual** for a series of points in time?

Examples:

- *Goal* vs *Actual* sales in each quarter of the year
- *Forecast* vs *Actual* energy consumption in each month of the year
- Household expenditures, *budget* vs *actually spent*, each week of the quarter.

The obvious way is to simply chart a pair of lines, Y-axis is amount, X-axis is time intervals. One line for *Plan/Forecast*, another line for *Actual*.

Any alternatives are welcome. Specifically:

- I am using [Vaadin Charts](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/charts), with many examples in [this Demo web site](http://demo.vaadin.com/charts/).
- Vaadin Charts is based on [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com) with its own similar [Demo web site](http://www.highcharts.com/demo).

Comment: Hi Basil, unless there is a specific user interaction you are designing for, this question may be better suited for http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @tohster Thanks. I tried to flag the question to a moderator for migration to the other StackExchange. Not sure if I was successful.

Comment: I don't see how graphicdesign.SE works better. The question is about data visualization, something that very handedly falls under the umbrella of UX.

Comment: I have to agree with @EvilClosetMonkey.  If it were about the design of a given type of chart, it would be better on graphic design.  However this is about visualisation and how to communicate a concept, so I think it's a valid UX question.

Answer (score 3):

Don't overcomplicate it by trying to figure out something neat and cutting edge. People get a simple x- and y-axis with a few lines on it.

With the graph below, I can see instantly how the two numbers relate. I can see that in 2001 things went *really* well, and I can easily point this out when yelling at middle management as to why we still aren't doing that well.

[image]

Combination graphs can also be useful if you want to show several different types of related data in one graph.

[image]

Both are simple and straight forward. I can easily pull the two numbers I need (3 in the case of the 2nd graph) and do what I need with them.

(Graph Credit: [Correlate and Compare Graphs](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/ux/applications/DPG/OBIEE/patterns/correlate_compare/index.html))